# Why didn't Gremmy Thoumeaux just imagine Kenpachi dead?

Tags: bleach

If Gremmy Thoumeaux can imagine anything and make it really happen, and if he's really that mad, why didn't he just imagine Kenpachi dying without any talk and fights?

Comment: Largely because by that point in the series, the writing had gone hit rock bottom and nothing anyone does or doesn't do makes any sense.

Comment: essentially as we see, his power relies on his own strength of will verses his opponents strength of will, kenpachi single focus in life is to kill, so he obviously wins because hes kenpachi :D/

Comment: No, gremmy defeated because he cant handle the power he imagined he has, which is the power that is stronger than kenpachi. Thats why hes dead. And also, because maybe hes just too stupid not to just imagine kenpachi dead straight away. Well. If the reason is that hes too stupid, its kinda hard to accept

Comment: I read this few days back and if i remember correctly there is one scene in which kenpachi tells greemy that he imagined him as a monster and that monster killed him.

Answer (score 3):

Gremmy lost because:

> He imagined that he was as strong as Kenpachi but he failed to imagine that his body was strong enough to contain Kenpachi's power and thus the power tore Gremmy's body apart. Furthermore, Kenpachi also caused Gremmy to doubt himself and imagine his own defeat and death. So Kenny won because his imagination was greater than Gremmy's! Irony!
>
> And this is speculation on my part but Gremmy doesn't seem to have the power to will someone dead. Certainly not someone as powerful as Kenpachi.
>
> Gremmy was always creating physical objects to destroy Kenny (meteorite, guns, missiles etc.). The exception was Yachiro, but Gremmy touched her to turn her bones into cookies; I'll have to review the battle to see if Gremmy ever touched Kenny.

And the out of universe answer is that it would be a pretty lame fight if Gremmy could just imagine his enemies to death. So there has to be some challenge, drama and limitations in play.

Answer (score 1):

Because Gremmy would have to physically touch Kenpachi first to do that. This is heavily implied given the fact that he only made Yachiru into cookies RIGHT AFTER he touched her hand.

Answer (score 0):

Gremmy wants to have a toe to toe fight with Kenpachi because he wants Kenpachi to challenge him. That's why he didn't lift any of his fingers.

Comment: Do you have any evidence you could [edit] in that this is indeed the reason why he wanted to fight him?